# mysql maximum row size

Tags: mysql, database, size

I don't know why I'm having this odd behaviour on `mysql 5.6.24` , can you help me ? do you think it's a bug

```
mysql -D database --default_character_set utf8 -e "ALTER TABLE abc_folder ADD COLUMN lev10 varchar(5000);"
```

> ERROR 1118 (42000) at line 1: Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs

instead

```
 mysql -D database --default_character_set utf8 -e "ALTER TABLE abc_folder ADD COLUMN lev10 varchar(50000);"
```

In other words a bigger varchar() entry is accepted and correctly working.
Does anybody know what is going on ?

Comment: I assume that somewhere the `varchar()` is turned into some type of `text` data type, but I can't find a reference to this in the documentation.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE fnbl_folder`.  It may help with @GordonLinoff 's comment, and it may explain what happened.

Answer (score 1):

This error means that in your table abc_folder, one single line would be bigger than 65535 bytes without columns of type TEXT or BLOBS.
65535 is the highest number which can be represented by an unsigned 16-bit binary number. And as stated [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-restrictions.html) :

> Although InnoDB supports row sizes larger than 65,535 bytes internally, MySQL itself imposes a row-size limit of 65,535 for the combined size of all columns:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE t (a VARCHAR(8000), b VARCHAR(10000),
    -> c VARCHAR(10000), d VARCHAR(10000), e VARCHAR(10000),
    -> f VARCHAR(10000), g VARCHAR(10000)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
ERROR 1118 (42000): Row size too large. The maximum row size for the
used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. You have to change some
columns to TEXT or BLOBs
```

This means that internally, MySQL is probably using a 16 byte number to store the size of a row.

To correct your error, I would suggest changing VARCHAR(5000) into TEXT or to use multiple tables.
Using TEXT if you want to impose a limit of 5000 bytes on your column, you should use a truncate function when inserting into the table. You can use [substr](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) for that.

```
INSERT INTO abc_folder (lev10) VALUES (SUBSTR('Some Text',0, 5000))
```